# Hibernate: ManytoMany mapping: "Two-way"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two class:

Order.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", catalog = "ownDB")
public class Order {

    private int orderNO;
    private String oderName;
    private Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<Room>(0);

    public Order(int orderNo, String orderName, Set<Room> rooms) {
        this.oderNo = orderNo;
        this.orderName = orderName;
        this.rooms = rooms;  
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "orderNO", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 6)
    public int getOrderNO() {
        return this.orderNO;
    }

    public void setOrderNo(int OrderNO) {
        this.orderNO = orderNO;
    }

    @Column(name = "orderName", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getOrderName() {
        return this.orderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
        this.orderName = orderName;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "rooms_orders", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "orderNO") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roomNO") })
    public Set<Room> getRoom() {
        return this.rooms;
    }

    public void setRoom(Set<Room> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }
}
```

And this is the room.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rooms", catalog = "ownDB")
public class  {

    private int roomNO;
    private String name;
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>(0);

    public Room(int roomNO, String name, Set<Order> orders) {
        this.roomNO = roomNO;
        this.name = name;
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "roomNO", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 6)
    public int getRoomNO() {
        return this.roomNO;
    }

    public void setRoomNO(int roomNO) {
        this.roomNO = roomNO;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "rooms_orders", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roomNO") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "orderNO") })
    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return this.orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE  TABLE rooms (
  roomNO int(6) NOT NULL ,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (roomNO));

CREATE  TABLE orders (
    orderNO int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orderName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (orderNO));

CREATE TABLE rooms_orders (
    roomNO int(6) NOT NULL,
    orderNO int (6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (roomNO, orderNO));
```

What is the problem with the two mapping? It is works for me. But I don't want to use, if it isn't the right way. If I am change the second mapping to "@ManyToMany(mappedBy="room")" (without the joinTable annotation) in the Order class. I can't list all rooms (with their orders), because I got this error message:

"Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.room.model.Room.orders, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

What is the right way to can list all orders with their rooms and all rooms with their orders. So I need "two-way" join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in the code you posted.

First of all, your join table is not correctly defined. It shouldn't have a seperate column for the ID: noone will ever populate this column. It should be defined as

```
CREATE TABLE rooms_orders (
    roomNO int(6) NOT NULL,
    orderNO int (6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rommNO, orderNO));
```

Second, your mapping is wrong. A bidirectional association always has an owner side, which defines how the association is mapped, and an inverse side, which uses the mappedBy attribute to tell JPA that this is the inverse side, and where to find the owner side. So, in Room, the association should be mapped with

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rooms")
public Set<Order> getOrders() {
    return this.orders;
}
```

And finally, your mapping for the association doesn't match with the column names in your table:

```
@JoinTable(name = "rooms_orders", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "orderNO") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roomNumber") })
```

There is no column "roomNumber" in the table. The column is named "roomNO".

Comment: OK, I edited my sql tables, but not "mappedBy="room" is the right way? The third error still edited. But the roomNO is still zero in the rooms_orders table.

Comment: `mappedBy = "room" `is indeed correct, since you chose to name your method `getRoom()`. But an order has **several** rooms, so you should really rename the getter `getRooms()`. For the rest, show your code.

Comment: I know this is not fair to the site's other users, but my code is very big and I don't know which part has the error. Can I send to you in e-mail or something like that? And If we find the solution, I post it.

Comment: No. You should be able to identify the **relevant** code, or to write a small example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Can you review my code, if you'll have free time? This is very important for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: It's far too long, and contains a whole lot of irrelevent code. Just create a simple use case doing exactly waht you want, i.e. the 3 or 4 lines of code that add the order and/od the rooms using your entities and the entityManager. You should implement a unit test that does exactly what you want to test.

Comment: Sorry, but I think every code is relevent here. Please take a look at it! I don't think it is more than a several minutes for you, and can save my life. :)

Comment: But there are too many potential sources for the problem. It could be the JSP, the controller, the service, the DAO, the inputs (that I don't know), the database. You want to test your mapping, so test that, and that only. When you know the mapping is right, then start testing the other components. That said, your roomNO is not auto-generated so, if you don't assign any value to it, then its value will be 0. The OrderNO is autogenerated by the database, but you haven't told JPA about it, so JPA doesn't know it.

Comment: Okay I changed the question. And concentrate only one error at now.

Comment: You keep changing your question agian and again. Don't do that. Reagarding the lazy initialization exception, google for your error messages, and you'll find dozens of explanations about it.